# jquery slider background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to web programming and I am trying to create website that contains slider. I am currently using jquery to create the slider. I am trying to change the background color of the slider to red when the slider value is less than 5 and to green when it is greater than 5. How do I accomplish this? Would I have to use CSS to accomplish this? If so, how am I supposed to integrate CSS along with the jquery code.

Here is my progress so far:

**EDIT** I tried using .css() on the slider element and setting the `background-color` property to `#ff0000`, but that did not work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range with fixed maximum</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      value: 0,
      step: .001,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        if(ui.value < 5){
          $("#amount").attr("style","border:0; color:#ff0000; font-weight:bold;");
          $( "#slider-range-max" ).css("background-color","#ff0000");
         }
        else
          $("#amount").attr("style","border:0; color:#00ff00; font-weight:bold;");

      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
  <label for="amount">Trust Value:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#ff0000; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery UI uses the property `background` which is more important than your property `background-color`. Change your `$( "#slider-range-max" ).css("background-color","#ff0000");` to `$( "#slider-range-max" ).css("background","#ff0000");` and it works.

Also, don't forget to put the background change into your `else` statement, or else it'll stay red, even when amount is more than 5.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVRLv/).  See if this works for what you need.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      value: 0,
      step: .001,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        if(ui.value < 5){
          $("#amount").attr("style","border:0; color:#ff0000; font-weight:bold;");
          $('#slider-range-max').removeClass('green');
          $('#slider-range-max').addClass('red');

        }
         else{
          $("#amount").attr("style","border:0; color:#00ff00; font-weight:bold;");
            $('#slider-range-max').removeClass('red');
          $('#slider-range-max').addClass('green');
         }

      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });


.ui-widget-header{
    background: none;
}
.red .ui-slider-range {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.green .ui-slider-range {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement like this. The default color should be red (#ff0000) and when the value of #amount is > 5 it animates the color to green.

```
if($('#amount').val(); > 5){
    $('#amount').animate({"color":"#00ff00"}, 1000);
}else{
    $('#amount').animate({"color":"#ff0000"}, 1000);
```

Alternately you could use `$('#amount').css("color":"#00ff00");` to change it instantly to green instead of an animation.

Quick tip: use single quotes for your jQuery selectors. Double quotes will break some selectors like this `$("#elem[type="text"]")` because it ends the open quote with the first closed quote it finds.