# How to change jquery slider color

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I have the jquery ui slider.
I would like to change the color of the slider bar to be green instead of the default grey. I've gone through my css and tried to add css as well but I don't seem to be able to change the color.

Here is my css

```
    .scroll-pane {
    border: 2px solid;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 7px 3px 0 7px;
    width: 57%;
}

.scroll-content { 
    width: 1086px; 
    float: left; 
    height: 481px; 
}

.scroll-content-item { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px; 
    font-size: 3em; 
    line-height: 96px; 
    text-align: center; 
}

.scroll-bar-wrap { 
    clear: left; 
    padding: 0 4px 0 2px; 
    margin: 0 -1px -1px -1px; 
}

.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider { 
    background: none; 
    border:0; 
    height: 2em; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-handle-helper-parent { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle { 
    top:.2em; 
    height: 1.5em; 
}

.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle .ui-icon { 
    margin: -8px auto 0; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 50%; 
}

.scroll-bar{
    background-color: #63a81f;
}
```

My html

```
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<script src="js/query.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script><script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.4.cystom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=2"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css?v=2"/>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,400italic,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

in the body section of the html

```
    <div class="column-right">
    <div class="scroll-pane ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <div class="scroll-content">
            <img src="images/image1.jpg">
            <img src="images/image2.jpg">
            <img src="images/image3.jpg">
            <img src="images/image4.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="scroll-bar-wrap ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
            <div class="scroll-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All my other stuff like the jquery ui smoothness css and the jquery-ui are the ones that I downloaded from the jquery ui site.
If there is anything else you need to know, please let me know.

Comment: You don't need to include both the jquery and the jquery.min version. The min version is just a minimized version of the js, and only one or the other is needed. I don't think that should cause any issues, but I could be wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery slider background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420040/jquery-slider-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Jquery:**

```
$('.ui-widget-content').css('background','green');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/1723/)**

**Using CSS:**

```
.ui-widget-content{
   background:green;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/1724/)**